# Constructor not defined: [APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew].<Constructor>(ApexPages.StandardController)

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, batch

Error :  Error while runnig test class. This vf is getting called from a list view button on the home page of custom object.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="EQ_BulkOrders__c" extensions="APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew"  action=" 
       {!StartBactJob}" recordSetVar="risks" lightningStylesheets="true"  standardStylesheets="true">

        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

        </apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew{

   public APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

  } 

    public PageReference StartBactJob()

  {
      Integer MaxOrdersPerBatch = 30;
      if(System.Label.APTS_OrdersPerBatch == null)
       MaxOrdersPerBatch = 30;
       else
       MaxOrdersPerBatch = Integer.valueOf(System.Label.APTS_OrdersPerBatch);

    List<EQ_BulkOrders__c> listOfBO=[select  id from EQ_BulkOrders__c  where EQ_BatchNumber__c =''];
    Integer CountBO= listOfBO.size(); 
  System.debug('*******CountBO count******'+ CountBO);
Integer NoOfBatches=CountBo/MaxOrdersPerBatch; 
System.debug('*******NoOfBatches******'+ NoOfBatches);

if(CountBO>=MaxOrdersPerBatch)
{
  for(integer i=1;i<=NoOfBatches+1;++i)
  {
      System.debug('********CountBO/NoOfBatches*****'+ i);
      //database.executeBatch(new APTS_BulkOrderCreation_Batch(CountBO/NoOfBatches>=MaxOrdersPerBatch?CountBO/NoOfBatches:math.mod(CountBo,NoOfBatches)),1);
      database.executeBatch(new APTS_BulkOrderCreation_Batch(MaxOrdersPerBatch),1);
      ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Confirm,'BulkOrder Batch has started....'));
  }
}
else 
  {
     for(integer i=1;i<=CountBO;++i)
      {
        database.executeBatch(new APTS_BulkOrderCreation_Batch(1),1);
      }
  }


 return(new PageReference('/'+Schema.SObjectType.EQ_BulkOrders__c.getKeyPrefix()+'/o'));
```

}
}

Test Class :

```
@isTest
```

public class APTS_BulkOrderBatchNewTest {

```
public static testMethod void draftOrderTest() {        
    Apttus_Config2__PaymentTerm__c paymentTerm = new Apttus_Config2__PaymentTerm__c();
    paymentTerm.Name = 'Net 90 days';
    paymentTerm.Apttus_Config2__Sequence__c = 1;
    insert paymentTerm;


    Apttus_Config2__BillingPreference__c billingPreference = new Apttus_Config2__BillingPreference__c();
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__Active__c = true;
    billingPreference.Name  = 'EQ Preference - April';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__BillingCycleStart__c = 'Period Start Date';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__BillingDayOfMonth2__c = '1st of the Month';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__BillingInterval__c = 'Anytime';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__CalendarCycleStart__c = 'April';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__InvoiceDeliveryMethod__c = 'Email';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__InvoiceOutputFormat__c ='PDF';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__PrefLevel__c ='Organization';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__ProrationPeriodTreatment__c = 'Separate Period';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__TaxLevel__c = 'Account';
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__Default__c = true;
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__AllowPaymentTermOverride__c = false;
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__AllowPrefOverride__c = false;
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__DoNotCreateInformational__c = false;
    billingPreference.Apttus_Config2__HideInformational__c = false;
    insert billingPreference;

    Apttus_Config2__LegalEntity__c legalEntity = new Apttus_Config2__LegalEntity__c();
    legalEntity.Apttus_Config2__LegalEntityName__c = 'Test Legal Entity';
    legalEntity.Apttus_Config2__IsDefault__c = true;
    insert legalEntity;


    //Insert Account
    Account account = new Account ();
    account.Name = 'TestAccount1-JPM';
    account.EQ_ClientRef__c = 'EQ146583';
    account.EQ_Legal_Entity__c = legalEntity.Id; 
    account.Apttus_Config2__BillingPreferenceId__c = billingPreference.Id;
    account.Apttus_Config2__PaymentTermId__c = paymentTerm.Id;
    insert account;

    Apttus_Config2__AccountLocation__c accountLocationSO_ST = new Apttus_Config2__AccountLocation__c();
    accountLocationSO_ST.Name = 'JPM ShipTo';
    accountLocationSO_ST.Apttus_Config2__AccountId__c = account.Id;
    accountLocationSO_ST.EQ_SourceSystem__c = 'CRM';
    accountLocationSO_ST.Apttus_Config2__Type__c = 'Ship To';
    accountLocationSO_ST.Apttus_Config2__State__c = 'Texas';
    insert accountLocationSO_ST;

    Apttus_Config2__AccountLocation__c accountLocationSO_BT = new Apttus_Config2__AccountLocation__c();
    accountLocationSO_BT.Name = 'JPM BillTo';
    accountLocationSO_BT.Apttus_Config2__AccountId__c = account.Id;
    accountLocationSO_BT.EQ_SourceSystem__c = 'CRM';
    accountLocationSO_BT.Apttus_Config2__Type__c = 'Bill To';
    accountLocationSO_BT.Apttus_Config2__State__c = 'Texas';
    insert accountLocationSO_BT;

    account.EQ_Bill_To_Account_Location_CRM__c = accountLocationSO_BT.Id;
    account.EQ_Ship_To_Account_Location_CRM__c = accountLocationSO_ST.Id;
    update account;


    //Insert Price List
    Apttus_Config2__PriceList__c pricelist = APTS_TestDataSetup.createPriceList('Test Price List');
    insert pricelist;


    List<Product2> listProduct = new list<Product2>();
    listProduct.add(APTS_TestDataSetup.createProduct('Product1', 'Products', 'Bundle'));
    listProduct.add(APTS_TestDataSetup.createProduct('Product2', 'Products', 'Standalone'));
    listProduct.add(APTS_TestDataSetup.createProduct('ProductOption', 'Products', 'Option'));
    insert listProduct;

    //create PriceListIteams
    List<Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c> listPLI = new List<Apttus_Config2__PriceListItem__c>();
    listPLI.add(APTS_TestDataSetup.createPriceListItem(pricelist.Id, listProduct[0].ID));
    listPLI.add(APTS_TestDataSetup.createPriceListItem(pricelist.Id, listProduct[1].Id));
    listPLI.add(APTS_TestDataSetup.createPriceListItem(pricelist.Id, listProduct[2].Id));
    insert listPLI;

    // Apttus_Config2__Order__c order = new Apttus_Config2__Order__c();
    // order.Apttus_Config2__LegalEntityId__c = legalEntity.Id;
    // order.Apttus_Config2__BillToAccountId__c = account.Id;
    // order.Apttus_Config2__ShipToAccountId__c = account.Id;
    // order.Apttus_Config2__SoldToAccountId__c = account.Id;
    // order.Apttus_Config2__Status__c = 'Draft';
    // order.Apttus_Config2__Type__c = 'New Business';
    // order.Apttus_Config2__PriceListId__c = pricelist.Id;
    // order.Apttus_Config2__PaymentTermId__c = account.Apttus_Config2__PaymentTermId__c;
    // order.Apttus_Config2__OrderDate__c = system.Now();
    // order.Apttus_Config2__OrderStartDate__c = system.Today();
    // order.Apttus_Config2__OrderEndDate__c = system.Today().addDays(30);
    // order.EQ_BillToLocationId__c = accountLocationSO_BT.Id;
    // order.EQ_ShipToLocationId__c = accountLocationSO_ST.Id;
    // order.EQ_IsLegacyRecord__c = true;
    // order.Apttus_Config2__BillingPreferenceId__c =  account.Apttus_Config2__BillingPreferenceId__c;
    // order.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
    // //order.Apttus_QPConfig__ProposalId__c = null;
    // //order.Apttus_Config2__Source__c = 'Account'; 
    // insert order;

    // System.debug('Order ' + order);
    // System.debug('OrderId ' + order.Id);
    // System.debug('Order-OrderDate ' + order.Apttus_Config2__OrderDate__c);

    // order.Apttus_Config2__Source__c = 'Account';
    // update order;

    // System.debug('Order-OrderDate ' + order.Apttus_Config2__Source__c);


    EQ_BulkOrders__c objBulkOrder = new EQ_BulkOrders__c();
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Client_Ref__c = account.EQ_ClientRef__c;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_CreatedByXAE__c = true;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Currency__c = null;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_ErrorMessage__c = '';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_LegacyData__c = true;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_LegalEntity__c = legalEntity.Id;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Name__c = 'Test Bulk Order';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_OrderCreationError__c = '';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_OrderCreationStatus__c = 'Pending';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_Date__c = system.Today();
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_End_Date__c = system.Today().addDays(30);
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_Start_Date__c = system.Today();
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Payment_Term__c = account.Apttus_Config2__PaymentTermId__c;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_PriceList__c = pricelist.Id;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_PricingCallStatus__c = 'Pending';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_ReadyForActivationDate__c = null;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_SFDCOrderId__c = null;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_BillTo__c = account.Id;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Ship_To__c = account.Id;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_ShipToLocation__c = accountLocationSO_ST.Id;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_BillToLocation__c = accountLocationSO_BT.Id;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Sold_To__c = account.Id;
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Source__c = 'Account';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Status__c = 'Draft';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_StatusCustom__c = 'Draft';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_Type__c = 'New Business';
    objBulkOrder.EQ_BillingPreference__c = account.Apttus_Config2__BillingPreferenceId__c;
    insert objBulkOrder;

    EQ_BulkOrderLI__c objBulkOrderLI_Standalone = new EQ_BulkOrderLI__c();
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.BulkOrder__c = objBulkOrder.Id;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_AddProductRequest__c = '';
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_AddProductStatus__c = 'Pending';
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_AdjustmentAmount__c = 0;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_AdjustmentType__c = 'Price Override';
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_ConfigurationType__c = 'Standalone';
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_CustomDescription__c = '';        
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_EndDate__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_End_Date__c;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_AddProductResponse__c = '';
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_LineStatus__c = 'New';
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_Location__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_BillToLocation__c;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_MinimumFee__c = 0;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_NetPrice__c = 10;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_Option__c = null;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_OptionCode__c = null;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_ParentBundleNumber__c = null;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_PrimaryLineNumber__c = 1;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_Product__c = listProduct[1].Id;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_ProductCode__c = 'pcode';
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_Quantity__c = 1;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_SellingTerm__c = 1;
    objBulkOrderLI_Standalone.EQ_StartDate__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_Start_Date__c;
    insert objBulkOrderLI_Standalone;

    EQ_BulkOrderLI__c objBulkOrderLI_Bundle = new EQ_BulkOrderLI__c();
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.BulkOrder__c = objBulkOrder.Id;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_AddProductRequest__c = '';
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_AddProductStatus__c = 'Pending';
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_AdjustmentAmount__c = 0;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_AdjustmentType__c = 'Price Override';
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_ConfigurationType__c = 'Bundle';
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_CustomDescription__c = '';        
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_EndDate__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_End_Date__c;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_AddProductResponse__c = '';
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_LineStatus__c = 'New';
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_Location__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_BillToLocation__c;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_MinimumFee__c = 0;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_NetPrice__c = 10;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_Option__c = null;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_OptionCode__c = null;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_ParentBundleNumber__c = null;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_PrimaryLineNumber__c = 2;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_Product__c = listProduct[0].Id;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_ProductCode__c = 'pcode';
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_Quantity__c = 1;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_SellingTerm__c = 1;
    objBulkOrderLI_Bundle.EQ_StartDate__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_Start_Date__c;
    insert objBulkOrderLI_Bundle;

    EQ_BulkOrderLI__c objBulkOrderLI_Option = new EQ_BulkOrderLI__c();
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.BulkOrder__c = objBulkOrder.Id;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_AddProductRequest__c = '';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_AddProductStatus__c = 'Pending';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_AdjustmentAmount__c = 0;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_AdjustmentType__c = 'Price Override';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_ConfigurationType__c = 'Option';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_CustomDescription__c = '';        
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_EndDate__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_End_Date__c;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_AddProductResponse__c = '';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_LineStatus__c = 'New';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_Location__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_BillToLocation__c;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_MinimumFee__c = 0;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_NetPrice__c = 10;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_Option__c = listProduct[2].Id;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_OptionCode__c = 'pcode';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_ParentBundleNumber__c = 2;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_PrimaryLineNumber__c = 3;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_Product__c = listProduct[0].Id;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_ProductCode__c = 'pcode';
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_Quantity__c = 1;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_SellingTerm__c = 1;
    objBulkOrderLI_Option.EQ_StartDate__c = objBulkOrder.EQ_Order_Start_Date__c;
    insert objBulkOrderLI_Option;

    Test.startTest();
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(objBulkOrder);
    APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew obj = new APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew( sc );  

   // database.executeBatch(new APTS_BulkOrderCreation_Batch(1),1);
    Test.stopTest();
}

// public static testMethod void pendingOrderTest() {
//     setupTest('Pending',null);    
//     Test.startTest();
//     database.executeBatch(new APTS_BulkOrderCreation_Batch(1),1);
//     Test.stopTest();
// }

// public static testMethod void activatedOrderTest() {
//     setupTest('Activated',system.Today()); 
//     Test.startTest();
//     database.executeBatch(new APTS_BulkOrderCreation_Batch(1),1);
//     Test.stopTest();
// }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

While errors from Salesforce can be very cryptic, this one is pretty easy to understand.

In the code you've provided, you only define one constructor

`public APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)`

It takes an `ApexPages.StandardSetController`
In your test code, you try to run

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(objBulkOrder);
APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew obj = new APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew( sc );
```

You're passing an `ApexPages.StandardController`

`ApexPages.StandardController` != `ApexPages.StandardSetController`

So you end up with an error message.

Your test needs to change so that it creates an `ApexPages.StandardSetController`

Comment: thanks for notifying me this miss. Everytime I was looking into StandardSetController I dint realize it is different from StandardController. I agree this should be same.

Comment: Even after making changes getting same error.   ApexPages.StandardSetController sc = new ApexPages.standardSetController(objBulkOrder);
APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew obj = new APTS_BulkOrderBatchNew( sc );